# ruby on rails: solid method to change logged in client's browser location on time X even when they reload pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, redis, real-time, faye

**Im in the need of changing a client's browser location on a certain time X. It has to be solid even if a user reloads page it should redirect to location X**

Below is my current (imperfect) implementation of this:

*Im in the need to a way to make this solution solid OR an alternative solution if that would fit better. ITs to complex to share code snippets so I would like to reframe from that and discuss the concept instead and discuss how to code wise implement the missing gaps to keep this question overseen able.*

**Current solution:**

- Im currently using redis and faye to send data to a subscribed channel (at the client) at time X
- This means that a jquery event (redirect of url ) will be triggered when the redis background scheduler pushes/sends this data at a certain time X ( which is always in future)

The problem is this is not solid, since on a page reload the pushed/send data is never received and rendered useless.

Even if it would be possible to save the last 10 sends/pushes in lets call it a "history" one could read it but say a user drops connection the excecution of this data would be useless since it will be to late and not in time.

*How could I overcome this problem? I prefer to keep the load server side and not use a client polling the server every 1 seconds to check if there is data received. that would not *scale* at all and would become a big problem if usage of the app grows.*

**What ideas on this concept to make it solid or use another method to get a solid implementation of this idea? any comments ideas suggestions welcome thanks in advanche!**